# Tagging Words Using VBA in MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vb6, excel-2007

I am having trouble sorting this out. I have an excel worksheet. Column A of sheet1 contains about 300,000 tokens and the column A of sheet2 contains about 15, 000 tokens with possible part-of-speech tags spread on the same row with each token. Format example:

```
A in sheet1        (A            B    C    D     E) in sheet2
now                may           NN   MD
earth              but           CC   CJS
between            can           MD   NN
been               think         VB   VBP  VBZ  NN
think              now           NN   JJ   RB   IN
may                between       IN   CC   CJS
red                ...
between
now
think
may
now           
...
```

my task is to take each word in A(sheet 2), search for it in A(sheet1). If found, copy tags on its row and paste the tags in cells adjacent to all the occurrence of the words found in A(sheet1). That is, if **think, between, etc.** are found, then I will have this output in sheet1:

```
A          B     C    D   E
now               
earth 
between    IN   CC   CJS            
been               
think      VB   VBP  VBZ  NN          
may                
red               
between    IN   CC   CJS
now
think      VB   VBP  VBZ  NN
may
now           
...
```

I have this code that does only the searching of non empty cells in A(sheet1) and A(sheet2), check whether each word in A(sheet2) is in A(sheet1). If true, then will copy the word (instead of the associated tags) and paste it in cells in C columns adjacent to results in A(sheet1). Result looks like below instead of above.

```
A          B      C        D    E
now               
earth 
between          between            
been               
think            think         
may                
red               
between          between
now
think            think
may
now           
...
```

Here is the code:

```
Sub CopyDataToPlan()
Dim LData As String
Dim LData2 As String
Dim iVal As Integer
Dim iVal2 As Integer


iVal = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
iVal2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

For LData_counter = 1 To iVal
    LData = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LData_counter, 1).Value

    For LData2_counter = 1 To iVal
        LData2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(LData2_counter, 1).Value
        If (LData2 = LData) Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LData_counter, 3) = LData2
            'Selection.Copy
        End If

    Next LData2_counter

Next LData_counter
End Sub
```

Also, this code when I try using it above 50,000 words, it either run and hang half-way or causes overflow. My aim: I prepared data in A(sheet1 & 2) for the purpose of tagging POS tags I developed to the words in A(sheet1). Words in A(sheet2) are unique words with most probable tags for it. Many users I employed for the task are more familiar with MS Office. So, I decided to make the job simpler for them. Instead of them going through the tags of about 100 and finding a tag for a word in A(sheet1), this system will provide them with a word and all possible tags for that word. All they will now do , is to take a word in A(sheet1), look through the tags provided and select one tag meant for it. Pls! I need help. Thanks guys!

Comment: You declare your iteration variable as an integer which in VB6 is limited to 32767. Try using a long. For reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420%28VS.60%29.aspx

Comment: See my answer below for a worksheet function method.  But if you must use VBA, I would set the ranges using something like range("A1",cells(rows.count,"A").end(xlup)).  And then use the Find method.  If you match, you can then copy over the adjacent cells in one operation.

Comment: I have tried using Long and it worked. But is there a way to increase the speed b'cos I noticed it also hanged half-way. Also, to copy the range if match found, can someone help me? I am stuck here! Thanks @Jac and Ron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this with worksheet formulas.  For example

```
Sheet1!B1:  =IF(LEN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$E$15000,COLUMNS($A:B),FALSE),""))=0,"",VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$E$15000,COLUMNS($A:B),FALSE))
```

Fill right to E1; then select B1:E1 and fill down to row 300000

Comment: I tried using this but isn't working b'cos I got blank cells all through. I think this process is straight against iterating each word in A(sheet2) through A(sheet1) to find matching words. And they are on different indexes in cells A:A on both sheets. Thanks @Ron. Any further help will e appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  And what do you mean by "they are on different indexes?"

Comment: oh! I am sorry if I did not give clear explanation. I used the second method you proffered, copied it and paste in B1, Fill right to E1; then select B1:E1 and fill down to row 300000 as you explained. But I got blank cells, though you will see that each cell has the formula. What I mean by different indexes is that words on A(sheet1) and A(sheet2) are on different cells. That is, you might see "may" on A7, A12 (sheet1) and only on A1(sheet2). Thanks.

Comment: If ALL the cells with formulas are blank, then no valid exact matches are not occurring.  Most likely there is something different about your "real data" than what you presented here (or what I understood it to be).  Blank cells in column A of either sheet1 or sheet2 will not change the behavior of the formula.  But if there is no match for sheet1!A2 in sheet2!A1:A15000, or if there is nothing in columns B:E of the matched row, then a blank will be returned.  What else would one return if an item in sheet1 did not have a match in sheet2?

Comment: If I didn't mention it, the data I used I copied and pasted from what you posted originally; then split the columns using Excel's text to columns feature.  The formula ranges (and sheet names) were merely based on what you had written for the numbers of entries, and locations.

Comment: you are right. It is working well. I looked at my real data and noticed some inconsistencies. It is even better and faster than VBA. Please, hope I can ask you questions in Excel in the future? Thanks man!